# Multiple sites with Apache

Tags: apache-2.2

I have defined 2 Virtual Hosts in Apache:

**Site1:**

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>

    ServerAdmin emt@gmail.com
    ServerName site1.mydomain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/site1/www

</VirtualHost>
```

**Site2:**

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>

    ServerAdmin emt@gmail.com
    ServerName site2.mydomain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/site2/www

</VirtualHost>
```

After enabling them, I try to restart apache and I get this error:

```
* Restarting web server apache2
[Fri Feb 14 17:06:15 2014] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 8080,
the first has precedence
 ... waiting .
[Fri Feb 14 17:06:17 2014] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 8080,
the first has precedence
```

I thought that as long as I had the directives `ServerName` with different domains, I could have several sites in my Apache installation. Did I miss anything?

Comment: Please at least glance at the [official documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/) before asking questions that are answered in the first few paragraphs under "Name-based Virtual Host Support".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need `NameVirtualHost *:8080`

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost

Comment: Now the URLs are working, but when I restart Apache2, I get this warning: `NameVirtualHost *:8080 has no VirtualHosts`. Why is that? Can I get rid of it?

Comment: @Dbugger: read the documentation on Listen and <VirtualHost>